# JPA - @OneToMany - Maintaining relations - Dereferencing old Object when setting new One

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I have a problem with a `@OneToMany`-Relation. I am using EclipseLink 2.5 and I am trying to maintain both sides and want to implement this directly in the `@Entity`-Classes, according to this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side) and [this](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/16/jpa-implementation-patterns-bidirectional-assocations/).

So, I have `Product` and `Manufacturer`, where a `Manufacturer` can have a list of `Products` and a `Product` have one `Manufacturer`. I want to implement, that you can change the `Manufacturer` of a `Product`. Therefore the `setManufacturer()`-Method of the `Product`-Class will be called:

```
public void setManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {

    if (this.manufacturer != null) {
        this.manufacturer.removeProduct(this);
    }

    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    manufacturer.addProduct(this);
}
```

So, if the `Manufacturer` of a `Product` is `null` we just add the `Product` to the `products`-List of `Manufacturer`. Up to here all things are operating fine.

But if a `Product` already have a `Manufacturer` and then someone change the `Manufactuer` I want to remove the `Product` from the list of the old `Manufacturer`. Therefore the `if`-statement in the setter, it should maintain the relation.

The problem is then, when I save the product and go back to the page where I list all `Products` of a `Manufacturer` the `Product` where I changed the `Manufacturer` appears in BOTH `Manufacturers`. It is not removed from the old one.

How can I solve this within the `@Entity`-Class? I think I have to call the `merge()`-Method on the old `Manufacturer`, but I have no access to the `EntityManager` in it. And to do this at the `Controller` seems not to be very nice code.

So. Hm. It is driving me crazy. I hope you can understand what I mean. Thanks for any tipps and sorry for medium english!

Here are the two classes, I removed the non-relevant parts:

```
@Entity
public class Product extends ShopBaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    public void setManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {

        if (this.manufacturer != null) {
            this.manufacturer.removeProduct(this);
        }

        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        manufacturer.addProduct(this);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Manufacturer extends ShopBaseEntity implements Serializable {

    public Manufacturer() {
        super();
    }

    public Manufacturer(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    private List<Product> products;

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        if (products == null) {
            products = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if (!products.contains(product)) {
            products.add(product);
        }
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product product) {
        if (products != null) {
            products.remove(product);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in the entity code, do it in the business logic.

```
Manufacturer manufacturer = ...;
Product product = em.find(Product.class, productId);
if (product.getManufacturer() != null) {
    product.getManufacturer().removeProduct(product);
}
product.setManufacturer(manufacturer);
manufacturer.addProduct(product);

em.merge(product);
em.merge(manufacturer);
```

The entity code should only be for managing the member variables and relationships.

Comment: I can not believe, that this is so much to code, just to handle the relations. Ok, this is one relation and is it not very complicated, but if I have a full application with many many relations this seems to be to much code for to few results. Is there not anything like container managed relations for Java EE 7 or JPA?

Comment: If the above code is in a CMB like a @Stateless EJB the two merge lines are not necessary as the container will automatically perform the merge when it closes the transaction.